# Why does string.Split(";") not throw an error if the string is null or empty?

Tags: c#, .net

If string is empty or null,

Shouldn't string.split(";") should throw an error ?

for me I am trying this code and goes through it without any error,

```
string a = string.empty;

if (a.Split(';').Length - 1 < 1)
```

Can anyone tell me why it not throws an error and why if statement is true.

Comment: You can just try =) It's easy.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b873y76a.aspx

Comment: -1. You just need to read the doc to find the information.

Comment: @AlexandreVinçon I was confused

Answer (score 64, accepted):

If the string is null, `.Split()` will (obviously) throw a `NullReferenceException`, like any other instance method.

If the string is empty, `.Split()` will return an array of a single empty string (unless you pass `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`).
This is a corner case of its more general (and less unexpected) behavior; if the delimiter does not appear anywhere in the source string, it will return an array containing the entire source string.

Answer (score 12):

It should behave [as documented](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/b873y76a.aspx):

> If this instance does not contain any of the characters in `separator`, the returned array consists of a single element that contains this instance.

An empty string clear does not contain any of the characters in `separator`, hence an array is returned consisting of a single element referring to an empty string.

Of course, if you call `Split` on a null reference, you'll get a `NullReferenceException`. It's important to differentiate between a reference to an empty string and a null reference.

If you want the method to return an *empty* array, use `StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries`. If you want the result to be an error, you should check for this yourself and throw whatever exception you want.

It's important not to guess at behaviour when using an API though: if you're in any doubt at all, consult the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

From your code, a isn't null, it's String.Empty. So when you split an empty length string by a semicolon, there's 1 item. 1 - 1 is less than 1

Answer (score 0):

An empty string is NOT the same as a null string.  Strings, being reference types will always contain "" if empty.  Null is not at all the same thing, thus, if you have an empty string, it will have a length of 0 and your if statement will be valid.

Answer (score 0):

The code splits the string into components separated with `';'` - the result of this operation is the array of strings. If there are **less than 2 components** the condition is true.