# Check to see if an array created with Split() is empty C#

Tags: c#

Tried a few methods, all of which should work, but I guess it is my lack of understanding of how the `String.Split()` method reacts to a null/empty string.

I looked at this question : [what should be returned for string.Split(";") if string is null or empty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14815721/what-should-be-returned-for-string-split-if-string-is-null-or-empty) and it is informative, but doesn't really help me out here.

This is what I have and if `ps.HeaderText` contains `""` or is `null` it still jumps into the `if` statement and I get an error saying that `Index was out of range.` Not sure why it keeps jumping into the loop.

```
if (ps.isSet)
{
    string[] splitHeader = ps.headerText.Split('*');

    if (splitHeader != null || splitHeader.Length != 0)
    {
        ps.headerText = splitHeader[0] + company[index] + splitHeader[1];
    }
}
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try `splitHeader != null && splitHeader.Length != 0`

Comment: you said "if ps.HeaderText contais "" or is null it still jumps into the if statement", well, assuming this, you said you are verifying headerText, s that right? Then, if i dont misunderstood, shouldn't you change the firts line to "if(ps.HeaderText != null && ps.HeaderText.Length > 0)..." ?????

Comment: i don't see any conditional over the ps.HeaderText   ...

Comment: @andre you are correct. I never was checking the value of `ps.HeaderText` and that is probably why it was unstable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> This is what I have and if ps.HeaderText contains "" or is null it still jumps into the if statement and I get an error saying that Index was out of range. Not sure why it keeps jumping into the loop

If the string is empty, you will get a single, empty entry.  This means that the length will be `1`, but you try to access `splitHeader[1]` (the second entry).

You can solve this by using `RemoveEmptyEntries`:

```
string[] splitHeader = ps.headerText.Split(new[] {'*'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

if (splitHeader.Length > 1)
{
    //.. Your code
```

Comment: I can't believe I didn't realize that... I think I will just check the string prior to the split.\

Answer (score 1):

You could check it before spliting the `string`, `and`, if has the P `*` char, for sample:

```
if (ps.isSet)
{
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ps.headerText) && ps.headerText.Contains("*"))
    {
       string[] splitHeader = ps.headerText.Split('*');

       if (splitHeader != null || splitHeader.Length != 0)
       {
           ps.headerText = splitHeader[0] + company[index] + splitHeader[1];
       }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like this, but I would only need 1 if statement. The other one is really redundant. If it doesn't contain `*` no need to parse the string.

Comment: Yes, maybe it also could be in the first condition `ps.isSet` :)

Comment: Ingenious! thanks for that one too! It's a big conditional but it's better than 2 if statements

Answer (score 0):

If `headerText` were empty your code would work fine (well that's not entirely true, `splitHeader[1]` would still cause an `IndexOutOfRangeException`). More likely `headerText` is null which means you'll get a `NullReferenceException` before you start checking the results.

So, add another check before the split,

```
if (ps != null && ps.headerText != null)
     //spit continue along
```

Basically, I don't think the problem is with your check against `splitHeader` although you should be doing `splitHeader.Length >= 2)` since you will be accessing the second element, checking if the length is not 0 is not sufficient for preventing an exception. You need to check it's length is at least 1 larger than the largest index you'll be accessing.

PS I clearly didn't read your question closely since you wouldn't make it to the `if` if `headerText` were null. However, that's still a place your code could throw.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (splitHeader != null || splitHeader.Length != 0)
```

You're passing this condition if `splitHeader` is not null OR its length is not 0. So if it's not null and its length IS 0, you pass.

Change `||` to `&&`. Also, like Reed said, check for `> 1`, since you're grabbing the first two elements.